# Can we use dbCommand and AddInParameter while inserting always encrypted columns

Tags: .net, enterprise-library, daab, always-encrypted

Is there any way we can use dbCommand and AddInParameter while inserting always encrypted columns into table  through .net?

db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@SSN", DbType.string, SSN);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how the .NET Framework Data Provider handles this - there is nothing you have to specifically do if the underlying object is a SqlParameter.

More details on this:
[Develop using Always Encrypted with .NET Framework Data Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider)

> The .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server automatically detects
>   and encrypts parameters that target encrypted columns.

I assume you are using the Enterprise Library. Looking at the AddInParameter method - it internally creates a DbParameter and SqlParamter inherits from DbParameter. Seems the same rules would apply in your case.

That being said, you may want to reconsider using the Enterprise Library in favor of straight ADO.NET, Entity Framework, or a micro ORM like Dapper. To the best of my knowledge, the Enterprise Library is not an active project / being maintained.

**Edit**

Seems you can pass a SqlParameter to the dbCommand.

**Example (not tested)**

```
            DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
            Database db = factory.CreateDefault();

            var dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spINSERT");
            SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("xxxxxx", "yyyyyy") {SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar};
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```

Comment: Thanks William, but the existing code used the enterprise library extensively and right now we dont want to change the whole code just encryption. is it something there is no way to make it Always encrypted column work with enterprise library?

Comment: SqlParameter inherits from DbParameter. So it should work. Also, it seems you can pass a SqlParameter to the db command. Though you should test  it out. I've edited my answer.